# Calling VF page for external objects

Tags: custom, button, lightning-connect

I'm trying to build out a call to a VF page that is referencing an external object from a custom button on the detail page.

I'm trying to figure out how to pass the ID of the record into the VF page. However as i can't reference this in a formula, the custom button to display the VF page of

```
 /apex/pdfVFPage?Id={!ExternalObject__x.Id}
```

is returning a syntax error that the field doesn't exist.

Has anyone worked a way around this issue?

Adam

Comment: Try to query external object then you can reference the id.